# Xib, Buttons open ViewController

Tags: swift, xib

Sorry for my english.
I have a XIB UIView in which there is Button.
How to do it so that when you press the button, the viewcontroller
[My XIB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNjFn.png)

[My Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rokn0.png)

Answer (score 0):

write in action like as ,

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController=storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"signUpView")
    self.navigationController?.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Comment: Error: /Users/yura/Desktop/3/CustomCalloutView/CustomCalloutView.swift:26:9: Value of type 'CustomCalloutView' has no member 'navigationController'

Comment: use navigation controller for your root view. embed navigation controller in initial view controller

Comment: Emded - Navigation Controller - Disable button's